# How to add an Icon for Menu in Ressource Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mfc

How do we add an Icon for IDR_MAINFRAME-Menu in Ressource Editor?

If I add the Icon for the correspondend Menu-Item in IDR_MAINFRAME-Toolbar, that works.
But I don't want see the command at runtime in the toolbar, only in Menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MENU Resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa381025(v=vs.85).aspx) does not support icons. If you want to add icons to a menu you need to do this on your own with the SetMenuItemBitmaps function.

But using the modern MFC extension, since ribbons were introduced, makes it easy to assign a symbol to command in a menu. (see [CMFCToolBar::SetBasicCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb983615(v=vs.100).aspx)). So the MFC add a symbol automagically if the same command is used in any available toolbar. Even if this toolbar isn't used (see [CMFCToolBar::AddToolBarForImageCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983344(v=vs.120).aspx)).